# Where does QuickBooks store the password?

Tags: passwords, quickbooks

I have tried to open QuickBooks Pro 2012 after several years (on a PC laptop, Windows 7), but I don't have the password. I received the license # and pin from QB, and did an uninstall then reinstall but it comes out to the same place, requesting the password. When I answer the security question, the screen says that the admin password cannot be reset and to check my Internet connection. Internet is fine. If the password is somewhere on the computer, I'd like to see if I can at least delete it and see if I can then open the program.

Comment: It isn't stored anywhere you can retrieve it or delete it, otherwise anyone could get it and open your quickbooks. Call quickbooks support.

Comment: have you tried following the procedure https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Account-management/Use-the-Automated-Password-Reset-Tool-for-QuickBooks-Desktop/m-p/202652

Answer (score 0):

if the data is on the computer you don't need a password you just need to tell the application you already have the password.  Usually involves a debugger and changer a single 0 to 1 in a hex editor.  Offline of course.

Comment: This obviously won't work if the data is encrypted though; theres a difference between there being a password 'bouncer' at the start screen, and the actual database completely encrypted using the password (although at this point it'd be backed up on Quickbooks' servers and OP wouldn't be having this problem as they could reinstall...)